# Make data appear on text input via button press

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i have form like this:

[image]

and database like this:

```
id   tagname  
1    horor      
2    race
```

and so far i have code like this:

```
  <div class="form-group">
        <label>Tags:</label>
        <input data-role="tagsinput" type="text" name="tags" id="myBtn" class="form-control">
        @if ($errors->has('tags'))
  <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('tags') }}</span>
        @endif
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  @foreach ($tags as $item)
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">{{$item- 
  >tagname}}</button>
  @endforeach
  </div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myBtn").value = "{{$item->id}}";
}
</script>
```

my controller code

```
public function create()
{
    $tags = tag::select('id','tagname')->get();

    return view('artikel.create', compact('tags'));
}
```

what i trying to archive is if i select button below tags input so it will appear on tags input text bar of course it will not just add 1 value but can select multiple button and make it appears on that text input and automaticaly separate by `,` like this:
[image]

.thnx for advance.

Comment: Is this a php/laravel question at all? It sounds all client side to me. If it is, please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with ONLY HTML, CSS and JavaScript plus possibly client frameworks

Comment: i already edit it, but sorry if i must include laravel tag or not because this created on laravel 7

Comment: If the issue is all client based then we do not care how the page was made. If you do not have anything PHP/Laravel related in the code you are having trouble with, then please leave out the PHP from the code and remove the tag from the list. Many ppl will ignore the question if they do not know the concepts in the tag. I for example do not do PHP, but guessed it was a client question. Please edit the question as I suggested and create a snippet with RENDERED HTML and JS/CSS only - we do not even nee your controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not using framwrok, use html javascript to show it work.

html :

```
<input type="text" name="tags" id="myBtn" class="form-control">

  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" value='horor'>horor</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction2(this)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" value='race'>race</button>

<script>
function myFunction(me) {
    txt = document.getElementById("myBtn").value;

    if( txt == '' ) {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").value = me.value;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").value += ',' + me.value;
    }
}

function myFunction2(me) {
    txt = document.getElementById("myBtn").value;

    // skip duplicate
    if( txt.search( me.value ) >= 0 ) {
        return;
    }
    
    if( txt == '' ) {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").value = me.value;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").value += ',' + me.value;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is best answer i just use function myFunction2(me) . this exacly what i want ty .@Flash Ang